# QNAP FTP users cannot login (admin login does work) - not network related

Tags: ftp, qnap

This question pertains to a QNAP model TVS-1282T (Version: `4.4.1.1117`).

We've been having issues connecting to our FTP over WAN. The admin user is able to connect just fine, but any other user (that does have RW access to the FTP share) cannot.

This is the client (FileZilla) output (personal information is obfuscated).

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.<our_domain>
Status: Connecting to <our_wan_ip>:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Command:    USER ftpuser
Response:   331 Password required for ftpuser
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

I've confirmed the following:

- Definitely not a credential typo - I've reset the password multiple times to make sure.
- This is not network related - given that the admin user can connect + the error also happens over LAN.
- Error is not VPN related. I've made sure to test with it off whenever I changed a setting.
- FTP correctly uses the /FTP share.
- `ftpuser` has RW access on the FTP share.
- Enabling anonymous logins did not seem to help.

The threads I've found from googling have either mentioned outdated firmware (several years ago) or the OP was doing something with SFTP, which is supposed to be admin only. These were not relevant to our case unfortunately.

Did I overlook a setting somewhere? I'm not familiar with the FTP server that QNAP uses so not sure where to start looking on the terminal.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to configure the FTP of the QNAP directly so instead I've setup vsftpd (on a VM) and mounted the FTP share via NFS.

Configuration of vsftpd is relatively straightforward through a combination of vsftpd.conf + standard UNIX file permissions. One thing to keep in mind is to keep the UID (and GID if you use those) in sync between the QNAP and the FTP server.

In my case, I created an ftproot user on the QNAP and checked it's ID in the terminal (`id ftproot`). I then created an ftproot user on the VM with the same UID. All other users and groups I've then set on the FTP machine (as you would in any other case).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reboot it.

If the issue persist you can upgrate firmware to lastest version(currently is 4.5.2.1566 build 20210202 of 2021-02-02), you can download it automatically on QNAP or https://www.qnap.com/en/download?model=tvs-1282t&category=firmware

Comment: Will give it a try. I'll report back in a few minutes.

Comment: Updated to 4.5.2.1566 - did not solve the isse :(